# MySQL Query many-to-one join

Tags: mysql

I have a query that I am using that uses ID from several columns that refer to one table to get the information about that ID.  Here is the code:

```
SELECT `Events`.EventID,
       `Events`.AssociationID,
       `Events`.Association2ID,
       `Events`.Association3ID,
       `Events`.Association4ID,
       `Events`.Association5ID,
       `Events`.DateFrom,
       `Events`.DateTo,
       `Events`.EventName,
       `Events`.VenueID,
       `Events`.TestnTune,
       `Events`.ShownShine,
       `Events`.SpecialInfo,
       `Events`.OtherInfo,
       `Events`.Rating,
       `Events`.EventOverlay,
       `Events`.HavePictures,
       `Events`.IncludeInSchedule,
       `Events`.EventURL,
       Associations.Active,
       Associations.Acronym,
       Associations.OrgName,
       Associations.WebURL,
       Associations.LogoURL,
       Venues.LocationName,
       Venues.Location,
       Venues.longetude,
       Venues.latitude,
       Venues.Directions,
       Venues.SitePros,
       Venues.SiteCons,
       Venues.BasicInfo,
       Venues.SiteRating,
       Venues.HostedEvents,
       Venues.CurrentWeather
     FROM `Events`
LEFT JOIN Associations ON `Events`.AssociationID = Associations.AssociationID 
                      AND `Events`.Association2ID = Associations.AssociationID 
                      AND `Events`.Association3ID = Associations.AssociationID 
                      AND `Events`.Association4ID = Associations.AssociationID 
                      AND `Events`.Association5ID = Associations.AssociationID
LEFT JOIN Venues ON `Events`.VenueID = Venues.VenueID
    WHERE `Events`.DateFrom >= NOW()
```

What I want to do is capture the detail information about each ID. I cannot figure out how that is done.  For example:

```
For Association2ID:
    Associations.Active,
    Associations.Acronym,
    Associations.OrgName,
    Associations.WebURL,
    Associations.LogoURL

For Association3ID
    Associations.Active,
    Associations.Acronym,
    Associations.OrgName,
    Associations.WebURL,
    Associations.LogoURL,
etc.
```

Comment: Well you appear to be selecting these columns. What isn't happening that you want to be? Ah I see you probably need to use `or` not `and` - and a redesign of your database to put it into first normal form!

Comment: Any time I find myself tempted to add a number to the end of a field name, it means my database schema is wrong - if you have more than 1 of anything (including FK references), put it in a new table!

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `JOIN` to

```
LEFT JOIN Associations ON 
Associations.AssociationID IN (`Events`.AssociationID,
                               `Events`.Association2ID, 
                               `Events`.Association3ID, 
                               `Events`.Association4ID, 
                               `Events`.Association5ID)
```

Does that improve things?

You probably also should consider restructuring things into [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Rather than having 5 columns reserved for potential AssociationID's the normal way of modelling this many to many relationship id to use a junction table with two columns `AssociationID`  and `EventId`